# Perturbation Theory Problem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, perturbation-theory

I am self studying for upcoming exams and I am stuck on the end of a problem related to perturbation theory. Here is the problem

[image]

I can't manage to do the very last part -- showing the exact change in all of the energy levels. I have tried to factor the new Hamiltonian to get a change in the energy levels but it's not coming out. Has anyone got any ideas?

Comment: can you explain how I should have written this for it to be acceptable, please?

Comment: In the case of 'homework-like questions,' whether they are homework or not, you need to specify why you do not understand a part of the method required. In addition, some effort to work through the problem must be demonstrated - whether it is correct or not doesn't matter, as long as you show your reasoning. With a decent introduction to perturbation theory, the last part should be straightforward, so see: http://www-thphys.physics.ox.ac.uk/people/JamesBinney/qb.pdf, chapter 9 which covers perturbation theory in explicit detail.